# Microsoft.Test.CommandLineParsing which dll is this in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have recently inherited a c# .net v4 project from a former colleague which contains the following declaration:

```
using Microsoft.Test.CommandLineParsing;
```

I have search google and our entire repository tree for this but cannot for the life of me find the required DLL for this.

The part "Test" is the bit which is not being found so I assumed there was a Microsoft.Test.dll - No such luck!

Can someone enlighten me as to which MS DLL I need to reference in order for this to be used.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That namespace is from the [TestApi](http://testapi.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the thing I needed. Cheers.